Acer nitro 5 + Ubuntu + контроль вентиляторов
У меня ноутбук acer nitro 5 (видеокарта 3060). Установил ubuntu и столкнулся с проблемой охлаждения (куллера работают постоянно на мелких оборотах и очень слабо справляются с  охлаждением). Нашел рабочее решение https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc, но проблема, эта служба вызывает зависания, клавиатура перестает светиться и ноутбук фризит. Какой вариант управления охлаждением можно использовать в Ubuntu для ноутбука?
